# Find Focused TextBox in a TabControl vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to add a TabControl to my text editor. I just need to find out how I can find the current textbox the user is editing in the tab control, so a button changes the current selected tab's text to "Hello World". The button is not located inside of the tab control.

Below is my code for adding a new tab to the tab control, it runs on a button click.

```
Dim tpTabs As New TabPage()
    Dim tbText = New TextBox()
    tpTabs.Name = "tpPage" & tcTabs.TabPages.Count + 1
    tbText.Name = "tbText" & tcTabs.TabPages.Count + 1
    tbText.Multiline = True
    tbText.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    tbText.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both
    tpTabs.Text = "Untitled"

    tpTabs.Controls.Add(tbText)
    tcTabs.TabPages.Add(tpTabs)
    tcTabs.SelectedTab = tpTabs
```

So every tab opens with a new textbox. New tabs are called "tpPage" followed by a number that increments one every time a new tab is made, same with textbox, "tbText" followed by a number that increments every time a new one is created.

So I want my button to change only the current tab's text currently opened to "Hello World!," then the other tabs when I get to them eventually.

Any help is appreciated, I've tried many things like TcTabs (which is the tab control on the form) tcTabs.SelectedTab.tbText.Text = "Hello World!," but I can't find a solution.

Comment: What if none of the controls currently has focus?

Comment: At least one tab will always have focus.

Comment: Actually a TabPage will *never* have the input focus

Comment: Oh ok, well what I was trying to say, is that there will always be one tab open, with the textbox inside of it, docked to fill the page.

Comment: How can you guarantee a textbox in your app will always have focus? Are you even sure your app itself has focus? That focus isn't in a different app?

Comment: Its a text editing app, if there are no tabs (meaning no textboxes) the application will close, and in order to accomplish what I'm trying to do here, are we relying on focus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CType(tcTabs.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), TextBox).Text = "Hello World"